# Feedback regarding my script and lme4package

Tags: lme4-nlme

I am struggling to generalize what I am reading (via textbooks, articles, tutorials) to my data - which led to my posting here! I appreciate any feedback from folks who are more versed in this stuff :)

I want to fit a four-level model in which observations are nested in students, nested in classrooms, nested in schools.

All students have unique IDs, all teachers have unique IDs, and all schools have unique IDs.  Observations are nested in students.

If I am understanding correctly, the below model represents an intercept only model with no predictors and only random effects, which would let me know how much variance in conduct is explained by the school, the teacher (or classroom), and student (students, nested in teachers/classrooms, nested in schools).

```
lmer(conduct ~ 1 + (1|SchoolID) + (1|teacherid) + (1|studentid), data2, REML = F)
```

or would it be

```
lmer(conduct ~ 1 + (1|SchoolID / teacherid / studentid), data2, REML = F)
```

After establishing this null model, I begin to add fixed effects. Semester (fall or spring) and demographic variables (ethnicity and gender), as represented below:

```
lmer(conduct ~ 1 + semester + gender + ethnicity + (1|SchoolID) + 
     (1|teacherid) + (1|studentid), data2, REML = F)
```

or

```
lmer(conduct ~ 1 + semester + gender + ethnicity + 
     (1|SchoolID / teacherid / studentid), data2, REML = F)
```

I am wondering: 
Do folks recommend that I add one fixed effect variable at a time and then compare to the null model?

What do folks think about adding a random coefficient for (fixed effect variable) by including it in the random part of the formula?

(i.e., `lmer(conduct ~ 1 + semester + (1 + semester | SchoolID / teacherid) + (1|studentid), data2, REML = FALSE)`

The intervention variable (Tier1TotalRatio) reflects a schoolwide intervention, well a fidelity score.  So each school has their own fidelity score.  All teachers within the same school have the same intervention score, as do all students within the same school. Due to this I am not sure if it makes sense to add the intervention variable as a fixed effect and/or random effect.  This is what I have so far:

first added as a fixed effect -

```
lmer(conduct ~ 1 + semester + gender + Ethnicity + Tier1TotalRatio +
     (1 + semester + gender + Ethnicity | SchoolID / teacherid) + 
     (1|studentid),
     data2, REML = FALSE)
```

then as a random coefficient by including it in the random part 
    randeffect4 <- lmer(conduct ~ 1 + semester + gender + Ethnicity +
                        Tier1TotalRatio + (1 + Tier1TotalRatio | SchoolID) + 
                        (1 + semester + gender + Ethnicity |teacherid) + 
                        (1 | studentid),
                        data2, REML = FALSE)

Am I making any sense?  Please help!

Comment: Victoria, welcome to CrossValidated.  You will get better answers if you ask something more specific. I know a little about lme4, but that doesn't mean I'll be able to answer your question(s). Try breaking your question(s) into small parts and asking one at a time.

Comment: Thank you!  I will give it a try :)

Comment: Just added lots of detail!

Comment: It may help to make the question less specifically about the software and more directly about the statistical/modelling issues. If your question *is* specifically about how to use the software, see the [help/on-topic], specifically the section relating to *programming*.

Answer (score 2):

The use of hierarchical random effects here is warranted, I think, and it sounds like you agree. What we "recommend" as far as the fixed, effects, however, depends on the scientific question. If you merely want to understand how much variability in the outcome is explained at each level, no fixed effects are needed. If you want to do that but "controlling for differences in gender and ethnicity among different schools/classrooms," then include those fixed effects.

I would forget about this "Tier1TotalRatio"--as you said, it's merely a school-specific number, and since you already try to account for variation between schools with a random effect I think it's unnecessary.

In general, it's a bad idea to fit numerous different models before clearly defining your hypothesis and establishing what you want to compare. If you're looking to demonstrate, say, a gender disparity in conduct, then think about what other factors you want to control for and fit a model with gender and those other factors as fixed effects (possibly with interactions).